# Do-while loops involving pointers to structs leave me with uninstantiated structs or strings

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

So when running the do-while loop at the bottom, 'pointer->next' isn't instantiated and so can't be a nullptr. How would I be able to loop through an indefinite number of stations and list their names while the loop functions correctly?

```
struct Station
{
    string name;
    Station *next;
};

int main()
{
    Station *index = NULL;
    Station *current = NULL;
    Station *pointer = NULL;

    string indexName = "Index";

    char addkey = 'n';
    char response;

    Station *newStation = new Station;
    index = newStation;
    index->name = indexName;

    current = index->next;

    cout << "Enter 'n' to add a New Station" << endl;
    cin >> response;

    pointer = index;

    if (response == addkey)
    {
        do
        {
            char addAgain;
            string newName;
            string fromStation;
            string placeHolder;

            cout << "Enter New Station Name" << endl;
            cin >> newName;

            cout << "Station List: " << endl;

            do 
            {
                cout << pointer->name << endl;
                pointer = pointer->next;
            } 
            while (pointer->next != NULL);
```

Comment: Sorry, I [can't even compile your code example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52434597c9c33588). So how are you believing that anyone could _macigally_ find the bug in your code? Post a [mcve] that reproduces your problem as required here please, best including your observations when running your code in a debugger, and what you observed when stepping through line by line.

Comment: please add complete code.

Answer (score 0):

When initializing `index`, you're never setting `next`, thus it's a bogus pointer value. You need something like:

```
    Station *newStation = new Station;
    index = newStation;
    index->name = indexName;
    index->next = NULL; /* must be initialized */
```

Also, I'm not sure of your intent with `current = index->next;`. However, it's probably not what you indent.

Of course, you'll want to actually add the new stations to the list as well, but I'm guessing you're waiting for that later.